# How are new probabilities computed when simulating measurement on a set of qubits?

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information

Suppose I have a set of 3 qubits and I have the probabilities for their distribution. This could be arbitrarily entangled or pure:

- |000> -> a
- |001> -> b
- |010> -> c
- |011> -> d
- |100> -> e
- |101> -> f
- |110> -> g
- |111> -> h

With it holding that a^2 + b^2 ... h^2 = 1.

a) Now suppose I wanted to measure the third qubit. Would it be valid to *generally* take the probability of the measurement being 0 as a^2 + c^2 + e^2 + g^2?

b) Assume I had measured the third qubit as 0. How would I construct a new probability distribution across my remaining 2 qubits:

- |00> -> w
- |01> -> x
- |10> -> y
- |11> -> z

Where w, x, y and z are computed from a, b ... h

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$P(0) = |a|^2 + |c|^2 + |e|^3 + |g|^2.$$
This is the probability of observing $0$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
w &=& a \big/ \sqrt{P(0)}, \\
x &=& c \big/ \sqrt{P(0)}, \\
y &=& e \big/ \sqrt{P(0)}, \\
z &=& g \big/ \sqrt{P(0)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Great, thanks for the help :) I was unsure whether the general form was that simple when talking about potentially entangled systems